# What was unclear about this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

[This question about Unix and virtual memory](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/how-did-unix-handle-multiprocessing-when-virtual-memory-didnt-exist) was deleted because it "needs details or clarity".

What was unclear about it?

Certainly, the questioner had some wrong ideas, but it seemed pretty clear what was being asked.  Are we rejecting questions where the questioner need to have his misconceptions corrected?

Comment: It was *closed* for supposedly ‘needing details or clarity’ by a community vote, and deleted unilaterally by Chenmunka for unspecified reasons. I would like to know those reasons as well.

Comment: @user3840170 -  Ah. I had aassumed that the close and delete reasons were one and the same.  It ain't necessarily so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was not deleted because of a lack of clarity.  The OP's account was deleted for other reasons.

The deletion of the question was a side effect.  Deleted questions can be undeleted, either by moderators or (I thought) votes from users with >2k reputation.

I should have undeleted it as soon ad I saw it had been deleted, that would have saved all this grief.  *Mea culpa*

Comment: The reason was stated as "needs details or clarity".  Am I to understand that was not in fact the truth?

Comment: Would it have made sense to delete the account but keep the question?

Comment: The question wss kept.  Users with >2k rep can undelete it.  I half expected that to happen.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think moderator deletes are unoverrideable by regular users.

Comment: I'm not sure on that one.  I remember voting to undelete a mod-deleted post on ELU a couple of years ago.  If you're right that is my mistake.

Comment: I didn’t even try because it was mod-deleted; just to confirm, I tried undeleting [this mod-deleted question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16333/79) and got an error message saying “A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted”.

Comment: on stackoverflow a non-mod cannot undelete what a mod deleted. Not the same thing for close votes.

Answer (score 4):

As much as I'd like to get an unfair advantage in the next mod elections, I can't say I would've done much differently to Chenmunka. When a mod deletes a user for certain reasons, the system tries to be helpful by automatically deleting all their “low-quality contributions”. Unfortunately, the question in question was closed at the time, so it ended up deleted.

Normally I'd leave it to the community to undelete the question, but [posts deleted by moderators can't be undeleted by normal users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86481/308065). (I only found this out by playing with [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/308065) in highly irresponsible ways.) As such, I've undeleted the question.

I can't comment on the reasons for suspensions or deletions (except to say this wasn't mod abuse). I'd rather avoid particularly rampant speculation, so I've deleted those comments. Please don't add them back again.

Answer (score 1):

I am just as disappointed by this moderation decision as another-dave.  But let’s clear some misconceptions of his own first.

The question was *closed* for supposedly lacking details or clarity, by a community vote of five users, with only my own ‘keep open’ [vote from the review queue](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/close/13512) opposing.<sup>0</sup>  Less than three hours after the close vote concluded, Chenmunka deleted the question in a unilateral diamond-moderator action.  The system doesn’t record a separate ‘delete reason’<sup>1</sup>, so whatever reasons there may be for deletion are generally only known by whoever performed or voted for it, unless those reasons are indicated otherwise.

---

I agree that the ostensible close reason doesn’t make much sense: even if based on a misconception, it was clear what the question was asking, and it was answerable by defusing the misconception.  The two answers under that question did so quite well.  There was nothing in the question itself to warrant closure or deletion: it was straightforward, focused, within scope, answerable objectively and politely written.

What to me looks like the *actual* reason the question was deleted is that in the comments, one user made a wild out-of-the-blue accusation that this was a ‘fake question’: though maybe somewhat ill-informed, the question was fine, as I said above, and did not fit [the usual MO of the troll attempts we tend to get](/q/943/).  The only thing that might suggest the slightest trolling was the asker’s (now-erased) username of ‘hehehe’, but even that is grasping at straws.  Later it is as if everyone else just jumped on the bandwagon with the close vote, pressing whatever buttons might get rid of the question sooner.  The moderator included, it seems, from whom we are yet to hear a justification.

This is not even the first time I see Chenmunka overusing unilateral moderator actions.  I hope those [promised moderator elections](/q/1065/) are coming sooner rather than later, because I already know whom I’ll be voting against.

I will also note that Super User had [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/321541/) asked and, though also closed, it was not deleted entirely.

---

<sup>0</sup> I guess whoever else might have opposed did not visit the review queue in time, which is the only way to register opposition to pending closures; and close votes from outside the queue may still render it moot.  But I guess the fact that the decks are stacked in favour of closures is a topic for another time.

<sup>1</sup> After all, closures are meant to be reversible and actionable on the asker’s part; deletes are generally supposed to be final and unobjectionable, so there’s not as much point in writing down the reason.